# Metrizable spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A topological space X, is metrizable if it is homeomorphic to a metric space.
I want to know, does this mean that all of topological properties of a metric space, inherit to that topological space? Also I'm asking, does all the importance of metrizability, is the inheritance of the topological property, or it has to be beyond that?

Comment: **If** the space $X$ is metrizable, then all that you know about metric spaces will be true for $X$. However, there exist nonmetrizable spaces.

Comment: You mean "all" in context of topological properties? Cuz I suppose they cannot be the same in every context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A metric space $(X,d)$ has a standard topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ associated with it, generated by the open balls in the $d$-metric. This topology always has special properties, that general topologies do not always have:

1. $(X,\mathcal{T}_d)$ is always first countable.
2. $(X,\mathcal{T}_d)$ is always perfectly normal (including $T_1$).
3. $(X,\mathcal{T}_d)$ is compact iff it is countably compact iff it is pseudocompact.
4. $(X,\mathcal{T}_d)$ is second countable iff it is separable iff it is ccc.
5. $(X,\mathcal{T}_d)$ is paracompact and monotonically normal.

etc etc. So if we know that a space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is metrizable, i.e. we know there exist some metric $d$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal{T}_d = \mathcal{T}$, or equivalently that $X$ is homeomorphic to a metrizable space (we then transport the metric on the homeomorphic space to $X$ using the bijection etc.), then we know that $(X, \mathcal{T})$ also satisfies the above list of properties. The $d$ is by no means unique, but the fact that it exists, means that the space satisfies all of the above properties (which are topological, and so are preserved by homeomorphisms).

There has been a lot of research on finding criteria on the topology on $X$ to know that it is metrizable, and many so-called metrication theorems are known now. It's not a very active area of research any more. But the theorems are widely applicable, and it's very useful to know a space is metrizable because of the extra structure this gives us.

Comment: Thank you. I asked because I have some difficulties with this kind. I've read some papers for cone metric spaces and fixed point theory. It is proven that cone metric space is metrizabile, but there are still many fixed point theorems that are not direct consequences from the metric space case. I do not know how to classify which are direct consequences from the metric case and which are not.

Comment: Maybe ask a separate question about these difficulties?